# Iphone soap possible?

Tags: iphone, web-services, soap

Since the threads about this topic was a bit old, I wanted to ask again, is that easy to access a soap webservice via iphone? I mean as easy as accessing a Restful service? or I have to do many tricks and magic for that, which tools can I use?

And more importantly, Is that easier and safer to create a Restful version of my web service or directly try to access soap service?

Thanks

Comment: yeah definately - go for WSDL2OBJC, i use it and it is awesome. it will read your WSDL and create the necessary files, and class objects for you. open source and is here -> http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/

Comment: thank you! some say it is not mature, do I need to change or correct the code it creates? does that also creates the set get classes for the objects defined in xsd?

Comment: no the code it generates you can use straight up, yeah get and setters are created for objects defined in xsd. Is pretty cool, not sure what you mean by mature?

Comment: in forums people complain about the code it generates and that they have to fix it..and it works for some wsdls and not for some

Comment: oh with you, well maybe for some, but in my experience the code works straight from the off. the only thing I changed was the address of the webservice as this is dependant on the user. Saying that, i did have issue with it parsing a web service that wanted a 'object' in its paranthesis. just keep with a defined type such as int, string etc and you should be fine..

Comment: @burrows I can compile the code, but there is very little code sample about this library, a few methods can you help me to find some source code how is this library used?

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but as far as I know, SOAP requests are very bloated in terms of request/response size. This is an important factor because your user might be using a slow mobile internet connection. So in that aspect I would recommend making a Restful version of your webservice.

Here is a nice post on how to incorporate the JSON-Objective-c framework in your app:

- http://blog.zachwaugh.com/post/309924609/how-to-use-json-in-cocoaobjective-c

Comment: Gzip-based compression is often allowed; of course, it has to be supported on both sides. Not that I disagree ;) just adding information.

Comment: SOAP requests and responses can be transparently compressed if the server supports it eliminating most of the complaints about the bloated nature of the protocol. I agree, if you're implementing a web service, using a restful API makes a lot more sense (but then I've seen it used as nothing more than an envelope-less SOAP protocol)

Comment: so I need to use an APi for SOAP? like wsdl2objc or iphone sdk is enough?

Comment: Do you mean if it's recommended to use a framework/library? I would say yes. In case you're not trying to do anything very exotic, using a framework can be a great timesaver